# Android Development: Text contain

Tags: android

i have a editText, so how do i check if the editText contain like "http://www."?

Is this possible to see if a component contain a specific string?

Thank-you

PS. is it also possible to change android:theme(like no title) at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC the titlebar needs to be removed in the Activity onCreate before you call setContentView.

I use

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

As for the text search use

```
String.contains("http://www");
```

Comment: Thank you for the contain method!

Comment: ooh and i have change the manifest so the title is not showed but i want to show it at some point at runtime. so is it possible to show...not show?

Comment: I would presume not if removing it can only be done before Activity.setContentView.  If you look at the Window class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html it may help.

Comment: the getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); must be called before you call setContentView.
Post your LogCat exception please.

Comment: So i can not change it in a method?

Comment: you can but the method must be called before setContentView.

Comment: I think you can only setContentView once in an activity :(

Comment: Your LogCat will tell you exactly what is going wrong.  Check Eclipse's DDMS or Debug views to it.

Comment: Post the code you're using for your `.contains()` check. How are you acquiring the String from the EditText? Just want to make sure you're not missing something simple.

Comment: if (edittext.tostring().contains("strings")){
but it doesnt work when add http:// :( why

Comment: @carefacerz.  It maybe down to the ://.

Comment: @sugarynugs what do you mean?

Comment: @carefacerz: You need to use `edittext.getText().toString().contains("http://www")`

Comment: @carefacerz.  what kcoppock said.  EditText inherits toString() from the object class so when you do a .toString() you get getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())

Comment: @ sugarynugs sorry i do not understand what you are trying to tell. so it is not possible to: if edittext contains "specificString" then do my code?

Comment: Ooh sorry guys!i feel so f-ing dumb that i forgot .getText() :O

Answer (score 0):

For Example

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i(tag, "onCreate");

    main = this;

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
```